# Explanation of syntax on GUID / UUID Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, uuid

I am quite new to JS and was going over the code for generating a GUID / UUID.

This is the code I found in this Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid)

```js
function uuidv4() {
  return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
    return v.toString(16);
  });
}

console.log(uuidv4());
```

What I am having trouble with is understanding this syntax:

```
var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
```

Can someone help me by explaining step by step what it does?

Your support is much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#binary_bitwise_operators

Comment: `var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0` removes the decimal. `var z = Math.random() * 16
console.log(z, z | 0);`

Comment: https://decimal.info/hex-to-decimal/3/how-to-convert-0X3-to-decimal.html

Comment: Didn´t know about the Binary bitwise operators. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
```

is the same as

```
var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0;
```

ie, create a random number in the range from 0-15 (or 0-f in hex) without decimal places. You could also write this line as

```
var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)
```

but `| 0` is probably faster ... And

```
var v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
```

ie, depending on the value of the current character to replace (ie 'x' or 'y') use either `r` or `r | 0x3 | 0x8` as value for the current place. The latter is because of specification of UUID version 4, that certain bits must have certain values. See [specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122) for details.

You can rewrite this line as follows

```
var v = 0;
if (c == 'x') v = r;
else v = r & 0x3 | 0x8
```

So `v` is still a value between 0 and 15, which is than converted to a hex char (0 - f) with `v.toString(16)`

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it with your explanation. I was having trouble at the end with the logic behing this part (r & 0x3 | 0x8). Turns out the character "y" in the UUID (version 4) must only be  one of the following values (8,9,a or b) nothing more. As for the rest very clear!